# T4MVC to have generated formatted URL (SEO)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, url, t4mvc

1) What is the best solution for working with T4MVC to have generated formatted URL (SEO)

I want to `MVC.AGENCY.INDEX (int? Page, int IdAgency)`

```
   http://localhost:30120/Agency/AgencyName
```

instead

```
http://localhost:30120/Agency?page=0&IdAgence=2
```

I can have this

```
http://localhost:30120/Agency?page=0&IdAgency=2&agency=agencyName
```

with AddMaperoute() but I don't want (`Agency?page=0&IdAgency=2`) in the URL

maybe change the symbols & and = by /?

2) When I add

> I use
>   http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/

```
<input type="submit" name=="Agency" value="" class="button bbrightRed mr25" />


public virtual ActionResult Agency (AgencyViewModel _AgencyViewModel)
{
....
View return (_AgencyViewModel). AddRouteValue ("AgencyName", AgencyName);
}
```

I want add some information URL

I have an exeption when i add `View return (_AgencyViewModel). AddRouteValue ("AgencyName", AgencyName)`;
Incorrectly Called T4MVC WAS. You may Need to power to regenerate it by right clicking will be T4MVC.tt and Choosing Run Custom Tool

My URL without AddRouteValue() is`http://localhost:30120/Agency`
And I want

```
http://localhost:30120/Agency/Agancyname/fff-llll-mm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `page=0&IdAgency=2` you have at least 2 options:

1. replace it with url like  `http://localhost:30120/Agency/AgencyName/2/0` and using `MVC.AGENCY.INDEX (string name, int? Page, int IdAgency)` (see Way1 in routing below)
2. remove id and page from the controller at all and map only by name (only when it is unique). You'll have `http://localhost:30120/Agency/AgencyName` and using `MVC.AGENCY.INDEX (string name)` (see Way2 in routing below)

To have seo urls you need to register routes. You can do that in `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`. [Here is a good overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



        routes.Map("Way1", "Agency/{name}/{IdAgency}/{Page}", MVC.Agency.Index().AddRouteValue("page", 1)
        , new { Page =  @"\d*" } );

        routes.Map("Way2", "Agency/{name}", MVC.Agency.Index() );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Here is I have created several extensions to be used with T4MVC

```
public static class RouteExtensions
  {
#region Map

    public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string routename, string url,
      ActionResult result)
    {
      return routes.Map(routename, url, result, null, null, null);
    }

    public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string routename, string url,
      ActionResult result, object constraints)
    {
      return routes.Map(routename, url, result, null, constraints, null);
    }

    public static Route Map(this RouteCollection routes, string routename, string url,
      ActionResult result, object defaults, object constraints, string[] namespaces)
    {
      return routes.MapRoute(routename, url, result, defaults, constraints, namespaces)
        .SetRouteName(routename); 
    }


    #endregion


public static string GetRouteName(this RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
  if (routeValues == null)
  {
    return null;
  }
  object routeName = null;
  routeValues.TryGetValue("__RouteName", out routeName);
  return routeName as string;
}

public static Route SetRouteName(this Route route, string routeName)
{
  if (route == null)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException("route");
  }
  if (route.DataTokens == null)
  {
    route.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary();
  }
  route.DataTokens["__RouteName"] = routeName;
  return route;
}

}
```

Comment: @chadis Thank you. I've added Get/SetRouteName methods to the answer.